# jscrollpane shrinks on click of a tree element

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

i have two Jscrollpanes arranged west and centre in the first i have a tree element and in second i have a plain area and based on tree selection content will be displayed.

however at beginning the size of a Jscrollpane works fine but if i click on any tree element the height of the Scrollpane of both are getting shrinked.

Tree Jscrollpane uses boxlayout and the other uses flowlayout respectively.

On debugging the shrink happens at AWT-Event dispatch.Am not sure what is the problem.Please help with it.

am not sure which part of code to show.Please ask if it is needed.

```
public class ListScrollPanel  extends JScrollPane implements MouseListener {
 ....
     ....

  public void loadNEList(){
    ListPanel = new JPanel(); 
    ListPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(neListPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
  ...
  }
  ....
    }
```

In this i am creating a tree structure in the Listpanel inside Jscrollpane.

```
  public class DisplayScrollPane extends JScrollPane implements MouseListener, ActionListener {

  ......

  private void init() {
    m_Panel = new JPanel();
    m_Panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    m_Panel.setBackground(Constants.PANEL_COLOR);
    getViewport().add(m_Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    setBackground(Constants.PANEL_COLOR);

    m_Panel.setVisible(true);


}


 ....
  ...
  }
```

This is the second jscrollpanel in which i have the Jpanel to show the contents based on selection of tree element in first scroll pane.

Comment: Try posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can better see what you mean

Comment: Can you duplicate this problem with a smaller piece of runnable code that we can try out?